# How do I style a Php <tr> tag under a table to size the font as x-large

Tags: php, css, styling

I need to stylise this  tag so that the text appears as x-large, I cant simply just do  in php as it does not work.

I've tried Styling but am somewhat unfamiliar with PHP

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "First Name";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "Surname";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "Home Address";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "Email Address";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "Phone";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Please provide more detail

Comment: Hey thanks for the response,

echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>";
echo "First Name";
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo "Surname";
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>"; 
echo "Home Address";
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo "Email Address";
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo "Phone";
echo "</td>";

echo "</tr>";

im trying to make the size of the different attributes x-large

Comment: Add your css code as well

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the code below might help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <style>
        table tr{
            font-size: 25px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo"
          <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>First Name</td>

                  <td>SurName</td>

                  <td>Email</td>

                  <td>Home Address</td>

                  <td>Phone Number</td>
                </tr>
          </table>
        ";
      ?>
   </body>
 </html>
```